# Can Greater Dispel Magic dispel a Wall of Force?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

In the description of [Wall of Force](http://paizo.com/prd/spells/wallOfForce.html), it says that it is immune to [Dispel Magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dispel-magic), but can either modes of Greater Dispel magic, either the 20-ft burst or the single target dispel the wall?

Comment: My interpretation was that Greater Dispel Magic differs from Dispel Magic, and as a more powerful version of the spell would be able to target the Wall of Force, though the Sorcerer in our party disagreed due to the listing of [Mage's Disjunction](http://paizo.com/prd/spells/mageSDisjunction.html#_mage-s-disjunction), saying it would be immune to Greater Dispel Magic despite not being listed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**No**
The text of *greater dispel magic* included in your link states:

> This spell functions like dispel magic, except that it can end more than one spell on a target and it can be used to target multiple creatures.
>   Additionally, greater dispel magic has a chance to dispel any effect that remove curse can remove, even if dispel magic can't dispel that effect. The DC of this check is equal to the curse's DC.

There is no mention *wall of force* in this exception clause, and *wall of force* is not removed by *remove curse*. Therefore if a *wall of force* is either targeted directly or included in the area, the spell functions as *dispel magic* against it. According to the wall description, the wall is not dispelled by this.

Note that the *wall of force* will also block line of effect, and so anything on the other side of the wall is not subject to dispel even if it would otherwise be within the dispel area.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment, we all totally missed the "functions like..." segment. Would have saved us a lot of trouble!

Answer (score 5):

From Greater Dispel Magic:

> This spell functions like dispel magic, except that it can end more than one spell on a target and it can be used to target multiple creatures.

So no, it would not be able to, because it's still limited by everything Dispel Magic is.

Comment: Yeah, we totally missed that, would have resolved the argument much quicker, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Dispel Magic and Greater Dispel Magic are on the same page of the [PRD](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/dispelMagic.html#_dispel-magic) (a good indicator they are closely related effects). The first line of GDM reads 'This spell functions like dispel magic, except that...'.

The language of Wall of Force indicates that it is immune to Dispel Magic, so I'd say that, no, the Greater Dispel doesn't affect the Wall of Force.

Comment: Yeah, we totally missed that, would have resolved the argument much quicker, thanks!